# C# background thread causes lag in UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, real-time

I'm working on a realtime imaging system.

UI thread: grabs images from a camera at 14 fps via timer and does some processing/display. Every 2 seconds, 3 images (about 1mb on disk each) are selected by processing to be written to disk. These are put in a shared queue.

Second thread: dequeues images and writes to disk. Has been given 'Lowest' priority.

When the second thread is performing the writes, it takes a noticeable chunk of perf away from the UI thread and causes capture to drop below 14 fps. Not acceptable.

What can I do here? I don't mind if the writes take a longer time and queue up, there's plenty of RAM and a regular pause to allow the writes to catch up. The critical factor is for the UI thread to have enough juice to work at 14 fps.

Comment: Are you invoking any UI updates from the background thread? It really shouldn't be affecting your UI.

Comment: Wait, why are you grabbing images from your camera on the UI thread?

Comment: Nobody has a single-core CPU anymore.  You are doing some kind of locking that slows down the thread that captures the images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a serious answer you should use some kind of profiler tool. If you search an stackoverflow or an google, you'll find plenty of them. Mostly you have to pay for them, but fortunately there also exists some trial versions which you can test to find the problem.

But my wild guess without any profiler is, that the I/O operation on the disk leads to your performance problems. So maybe you can work against it, if you try to use a [SparseFile](http://www.flexhex.com/docs/articles/sparse-files.phtml) and / or [MemoryMappedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(VS.100).aspx)s (i know it is .Net 4, but cause it is just a wrapper against the Win32 Api you can maybe extract the class from there and use it in .Net 2).

Comment: Thanks, just to clarify: the rest of the app doesn't touch the hard drive. Its not waiting for any reads or writes. Why do writes in another thread influence the capture/processing? Its a dual core CPU with one core saturated by the processing and the other free for whatever; I was hoping the writes.

Comment: I also don't have a really good explanation, but accesses to the hard drive always slows down the whole system, cause it seems always to be some kind of bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

realtime, windows and c# don't go well along together. if it's "not acceptable" for the framerate to ever drop below 14fps you could look for some realtime extension for windows, like [RTX](http://www.directinsight.co.uk/products/venturcom/rtx.html) or [INtime](http://www.tenasys.com/products/intime.php).

you could also try to write the files to disk in smaller chunks, add short Thread.Sleeps() inbetween the write operations to allow more task switches and make sure to flush the filestream after every write.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should save files to different location after performing operations on it. It's possible that file is being lock while processed and UI thread waits for it to be free.

Answer (score 0):

As other said: Hard realtime won't work here.

Try to find out if the devices share resources (bad example: Are on the same USB bus, both the disk and the camera). Check with a profiler if it is the CPU that throttles your capturing or the IO. Maybe it's just a fault of your code (leaking resources, wasting cycles). No one can tell, but you can (and should) check it.

Possible "solution", depending on your findings:

Use a queue (msmq for example) and just pile up images and never read from there (not even with reduced thread priority) until you reach your "pause". That would really require "ample amount of RAM" though.